# - C++ - launch exception with a Timer thread , precision ms

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, exception, timer

I need a timer that after 700 800 ms throws me an exception, what do you suggest?
There is something already written? I searched in boost but there wasn't nothing of interesting.

I want to do is something like this:

```
void method1(List l) throws TimeoutException{
    Timer t;
      t.start();
    while(!l.isEmpty()){
         //DO SOMETHING
         ...........
     }
     t.stop();
 }

 void method2(List l){
    try{
      method2(l);
     catch(TimeoutException e){
      //do something
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a small program that would use this?  It's not clear to me which thread should throw the exception in your question.

Comment: It sounds like there are 3 pieces here: 1) spawning a thread. 2) waiting for a specified amount of time. 3) throwing an exception. Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that's more clear after the edit. You could accomplish this by having `Timer::start()` spawn a thread that runs a timer and sets some kind of member like `bool Timer::expired` when time runs out. Then, with the appropriate accessor, your `method1` could do something like:

```
void method1(List l) throws TimeoutException
{
  Timer t;
  t.start();

  while(!l.isEmpty() && !t.isExpired())
  {
    //DO SOMETHING
    ...........
  }

  t.stop();
  if(t.isExpired() && !l.isEmpty())
    throw(TimeoutException(/*...*/));        
}
```

Someone should speak up if there's a simpler way using a boost async timer or something. I don't use boost enough to comment reliably on that.

EDIT:

I commented below with my concerns about corrupting data with the throw. If you still really want to forcefully interrupt the list processing loop right away on a timeout, [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293602.aspx) describes how to make Microsoft throw exceptions from one thread to another. Throwing across threads will normally be operating system dependent, but boost [does have some shenanigans](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html) that try to do this in a portable way. I haven't tried that method yet; looks like exceptions have to be derived from a specific base class to be supported for transport with the boost methods.

Comment: This isn't a good solution for my case, because when the timer is expired, I must immediately returns the control to method2()...

Comment: That sounds like it could be dangerous. since your `//DO SOMETHING` block is actively modifying (at least emptying) your list, stopping at an arbitrary instruction in the while loop will be very prone to corrupting your data.